# how to use Cordova with Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, mobile

I want to use the `Cordova 2.7.0` for my cross platoform browser based mobile application using the Jquery Mobile frame work.

I am new to phone gap and jquery.

i have downloaded the `Cordova 2.7.0` from phonegap.

but how to get the `Cordova-2.7.0.js` file from it and wher it is to be loaded and how it is to be installed.
using this i want to use the `Geolocation API` in Cordova.

please advice

Comment: Put both of the javascript files in your html page and youre done.

Comment: where to find the cordova-2.7.0.js

Comment: It's in the file you downloaded.

Comment: you are talkin about the cordova-2.7.0.js in the lib/android folder if yes will it work for ios and other platform

Answer (score 1):

Add the js file in the  of your index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
```

Do the same with jquery mobile file.
Regards, Daniel

Comment: but where is the cordova2.0.0.js how to get it?

Comment: i have downloded the zip file, but how to use it

Comment: Read the documentation for getting started...basically, include the js file as I tell tell you above, and then you will can use the api of cordova within all your javascript files.

Answer (score 1):

[Phonegap getting started](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides)

Follow the instructions there exactly. You have to create a new phonegap project from the command line also read this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/tnz2DnUE-E0 if you encounter the "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Path not found:  error

After everything is done you than simply include jquery or jquerymobile